# How do I add some columns to a generated SELECT statement in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-postgresql, pg

I'm a beginner.

My model:

```
class Publisher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
  has_many :transactions, through: :articles
  has_many :reader_profiles, -> { uniq }, through: :transactions
  #etc
end
```

My code that causes an error:

```
@profiles = publisher.reader_profiles
```

My error:

```
PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
LINE 1: ... $1  ORDER BY reader_profiles.transactions_count, transactio...
                                                             ^
: SELECT  DISTINCT "reader_profiles".* FROM "reader_profiles" INNER JOIN "transactions" ON "reader_profiles"."id" = "transactions"."reader_profile_id" INNER JOIN "articles" ON "transactions"."article_id" = "articles"."id" WHERE "articles"."publisher_id" = $1  ORDER BY reader_profiles.transactions_count, transactions.created_at LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

My question:

I obviously need to add these `transactions` fields to my SELECT statement. How do I that? Do I have to plumb in all my `JOIN`s etc manually?